# How to upgrade WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm running WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 and noticed 4.5 came out.  I've tried searching but haven't been able to find anything regarding how to upgrade to the new version without breaking files I've changed.  Anyone have any ideas or direct me to a document on how I can do this?

Thanks,
Jared

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no "upgrade" szenario available. We installed a fresh copy of ESB 4.5 and then copied our configurations from the following directories:

- lib/log4j.properties
- lib/core
- repository/conf
- repository/components/lib
- repository/resources
- repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default

But these were the directories where we know that we made customizations. If you don't know anymore your changes from the original 4.0.3, download a fresh copy and compare with your current implementation of the ESB.

Attention: The important axis2.xml has changed a bit in its structure - so copying the file as it is will not work. Just copy the changed configuration lines in it.

Answer (score 1):

For ESB specifically you need to pay attention to the followings if you have made any changes.

passthru-http.properties
synapse.properties
nhttp.properties

which were available under lib/core/WEB-INF/classes needs to be moved to repository/conf