# WSO2ESB Version upgrade from 4.0.0 to 4.6.0

Tags: wso2, upgrade, wso2-esb

Currently we are using WSO2ESB Version 4.0.0 in a clustered , load balanced enviorment with 
WSO2 Governance Registry Version 4.0.0. We are hoping to upgrade it to the new WSO2ESB Version 4.6.0.

Could you please guide us on followings,

1. What are the upgrading steps.
2. Do we need to upgrade the WSO2 Governance Registry Version as well.

Thanks
Rajitha

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this thread.
[How to upgrade WSO2 ESB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694477/how-to-upgrade-wso2-esb) (4.5.0 steps are usually valid for 4.6.0 as well.)

It is advisable that you upgrade Governance Registry to 4.5.3 which has new improvements and also lots of stability issues has been addressed since 4.0.0.